# Evaluate constant before displaying it in preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, evaluate

On this site I found tricks to display constant values in preprocessor, like:

```
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define VAR_NAME_VALUE(var) #var "="  VALUE(var)
#define A 5
#pragma display(VAR_NAME_VALUE(A))
```

that generates the output A=5

and they work well, but when I need to evaluate something like:

```
#define A 5
#define B (A*5)
#pragma display(B)
```

it displays the output B=5*5.

What if I wanted to display B=25? How should I write the preprocessor directive to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not, the macro replacement mechanism does not involve doing calculations, but you can take a look to GNU M4:

Besides just doing macro expansion, m4 has built-in functions for including named files, running shell commands, **doing integer arithmetic**, manipulating text in various ways, performing recursion, etc....

at built-in eval
http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Eval